# Unsolveability of the quintic on SNARK

Tags: snarks

All examples I find on SNARKs show polynomials of up to degree 3 or 4 but what about polynomials of degree over 5, what is the mechanism that allow SNARK not to be affected by the unsolvability of the quintic while calculating roots? Is there a high degree polynomial example that I could read?

Answer (score 1):

In SNARKs, the polynomials are defined over finite fields and the method of solution is different to finding an expression in radicals. Instead polynomials are solved using the [Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) which is largely a repeated use of Euclid's greatest common divisor algorithm. Note also that the Abel limitation does not apply to finite fields because the Galois group of an extension of a finite field is always cyclic and generated by the Frobenius automorphism.

I'm afraid that I don't have an example of higher degree SNARKs to offer.